# render() times out after 60 seconds with 503 - Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: cakephp

This code times out in a CakePHP 4.3.3 template with a

> 503 - Service Temporarily Unavailable.

In a none-CakePHP script it works [it shows after 6 minutes `DONE`].

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "0");
sleep(360);
die("DONE");
```

The template is called like this:

```
    $this->render("/General/index", "Study");
```

I didn't find anything regarding a max execution time for rendering but as I can clearly reduce it to the above MCVE, it must be something CakePHP relevant because in CakePHP it stops after 60 seconds, in a PHP file `timeout.php`, placed directly in the `webroot` directory, it works.

What am I doing wrong, what I haven't set up properly?

I think, I should present the log entry:

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1813:tid 140621247407872] (70007)The timeout
> specified has expired: [client XXXX:56968] AH01075: Error dispatching
> request to :

The server is running under Apache/nginx.

Comment: Are you using a similar `ini_set` call somewhere in your CakePHP script? Check the output of `phpinfo()` to see what the default setting is, I think 60 seconds is pretty standard.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I am very sorry, but I don't understand what I should check [similar `ini_set`]. All code is in the presented MCVE. Of course I checked `phpinfo()` before I posted this question and the value is `0`. Somehow it looks to me like CakePHP is restricting and monitoring the execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why a stand-alone script on the same server and same domain works, but under CakePHP it ran into the timeout - **with the exactly identical 3 lines of code**.

The solution was - after investigating the log error - the Apache2 `Timeout`.

Additionally, I had to set the nginx timeout settings:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 3600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
```

After applying the above settings for Apache and nginx it works also under CakePHP.